# Correlating a vector with edges in an image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement user-assisted edge detection using OpenCV.

Assume you have an image in which we need to find a polygonal shape. For the sake of discussion, let's say we need to find the top of a rectangular table in a picture. The user will click on the four corners of the table to help us narrow things down. Connecting those four points gives us a polygon, or four vectors.
But the user is not very accurate when clicking on those corners. So I'd like to use edge information from the image to increase the accuracy.

I'm using a Canny edge detector with a fairly high treshold to determine important edges in my image. (more precisely, I'm scaling down, blurring, converting to grayscale, then run Canny). How can I compute whether a vector aligns with an edge in my image? If I have a way to compute "alignment", my overal algorithm comes down to perturbating the location of the four edge points, computing the total "alignment" of my polygon with the edges in the image, until I find an optimum.

What is a good way to define and compute this "alignment" metric?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to use FindContours to detect your table or any other contour. Then build a contour also from the user input points. After this you can read about Contour Moments by which you can compare contours. You can compare all the contours from the image with the one built from the user points and then select the closest match.

Comment: Unfortunately, FindContours doesn't yield very good results on my images. The resulting shapes are often irregular (i.e. not nice rectangles), so just selecting the best one using the user input won't cut it. Thanks for the tip though.